# How to update NER model using BILUO schema in Spacy v3?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I want to add some PERSON vocab to the sm NER spacy model. To do this, I tagged names of Congressional officials taken from the ProPublica API using the BILUO schema. I have seen a lot of posts about using the dictionary w/ entities format. But so far can't find any where how to do it w/ the BILUO schema in v3. I have my data as a list of tuples. With the first value being the string and the second the labeled entities.

```
data = [('Nanette Barragán', list(['B-PERSON', 'L-PERSON'])),
 ('Jack Bergman', list(['B-PERSON', 'L-PERSON'])),
 ('Andy Biggs', list(['B-PERSON', 'L-PERSON'])),
 ('Lisa Blunt Rochester', list(['B-PERSON', 'I-PERSON', 'L-PERSON'])),
 ('Anthony Brown', list(['B-PERSON', 'L-PERSON'])),
 ('Ted Budd', list(['B-PERSON', 'L-PERSON'])),
 ('Troy Balderson', list(['B-PERSON', 'L-PERSON'])),
 ('James Baird', list(['B-PERSON', 'L-PERSON'])),
 ('Tim Burchett', list(['B-PERSON', 'L-PERSON']))]
```

I want to add these names to the already loaded NER model. I have been following steps from: [How can we use Spacy minibatch and GoldParse to train NER model using BILUO tagging scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64760271/how-can-we-use-spacy-minibatch-and-goldparse-to-train-ner-model-using-biluo-tagg). This referred to v2, however v3 no longer uses GoldParse as shown in the text taken from Spacy v3 documentation below:

```
  The Language.update, Language.evaluate and 
  TrainablePipe.update methods now all take batches of Example 
  objects instead of Doc and GoldParse objects, or raw text and a 
  dictionary of annotations.
```

The documentation for Example is shown here: https://spacy.io/api/example

Below is my updated script

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
import en_core_web_sm
import random 
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.training import Example

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()


if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
    nlp.add_pipe('ner', last=True)
else:
    ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')

ner.add_label('PERSON')

other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
    optimizer = nlp.create_optimizer()
    tags = dict()
    for itn in range(10):
        print("Starting iteration " + str(itn))
        random.shuffle(data)
        losses = {}
        batches = minibatch(data, size=compounding(4.0, 16.0, 1.001))
        # type 2 with mini batch
        for batch in batches:
            texts, _ = zip(*batch)
            golds = [Example(Doc(nlp.vocab, words = t), references = a) for t,a in batch]
            nlp.update(
                texts,  # batch of texts
                golds,  # batch of annotations
                drop=0.4,  # dropout - make it harder to memorise data
                losses=losses,
                sgd=optimizer)
```

However, I get the error:

```
   Starting iteration 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/36/j_203fcj42q9bvnlt1sl3j640000gp/T/ipykernel_162/1201951981.py in <module>
     14         for batch in batches:
     15             texts, _ = zip(*batch)
---> 16             golds = [Example(Doc(nlp.vocab, words = t),references = a) for t,a in batch]
     17             nlp.update(
     18                 texts,  # batch of texts

/var/folders/36/j_203fcj42q9bvnlt1sl3j640000gp/T/ipykernel_162/1201951981.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     14         for batch in batches:
     15             texts, _ = zip(*batch)
---> 16             golds = [Example(Doc(nlp.vocab, words = t),references = a) for t,a in batch]
     17             nlp.update(
     18                 texts,  # batch of texts

~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/training/example.pyx in spacy.training.example.Example.__init__()

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

I also tried replacing the Doc var below as in the original code but still same error.

```
 golds = [Example(nlp.make_doc(t),references = a) for t,a in batch]
```

I can't figure out how to get past this error. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not addressing your specific error here, rather you seem to have some misconceptions, so I want to be clear about how things work.

First, the NER model doesn't just use a list of words. You cannot just add a list of words to it. If you want to add those specific names, you need **actual sentences** that contain them to use as training data. But you also want a full suite of training data so just adding those names isn't a good idea anyway.

If you want to use the NER model **plus** you want to always recognize those names, then I would put those names in an [EntityRuler](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler) and put it before the NER component in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't sure if the way I was going about adding names was the right way since everything I saw did include using full sentences as you mentioned. And thank you very much for the suggestion on how to implement what I want!

Answer (score 2):

That error occurs because you passed a keyword argument, `references` to the [Example](https://spacy.io/api/example#init) class constructor, but the constructor takes two positional arguments and one keyword-only argument, `alignment`. That is, `references` is not a keyword argument for the Example constructor.

This should fix that error.

```
golds = [Example(Doc(nlp.vocab, words = t), a) for t, a in batch]
```

I'm not sure if the data you posted is representative of your actual data. If so, there is probably not much value to training a NER on it because it is simply a list of the entities with no context around them. In this case, you would be better off with a [rule-based approach](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) like a [PhraseMatcher](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#phrasematcher).